# Proper scoring rules for observations with different supports

Tags: model-selection, hidden-markov-model, scoring-rules

Suppose to have a bivariate variable $z_t=(x_t, y_t)$ indexed by $t=1,2, ..., T$. Suppose now that the two components have different support, i.e. in my specific problem $x_t \in \mathcal{S}$, where $\mathcal{S}$ is a circle, and $y_t \in \mathcal{R}$. I estimate a  model (Bayesian hidden Markov model) and then i want to evaluate how the model fit the data.

In other situation, where i had only a univariate variable, i used the scoring rules: if my univariate variable was circular i used the continuous ranked probability score for circular variable, while when the univariate variable was linear i used the predictive log scoring loss.

I am quite sure i cannot use a single scoring rules for bivariate distribution with different support. Am  I right?

What i need  to find is  a  number that summarize the quality of forecast. Any suggestion?

Comment: Is there a way to infer the score from likelihood in your model?

Comment: Unfortunately no